# What HTTP status code should I use when serving a temporary page to the browser?

Tags: html, http, http-status-codes

When the client submit something to the server, server confirms but cannot return the result immediately, and serve a page like

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5; url=/somewhere/else' />
</head>
<body>
Your message is accepted, and the page will back to the home after 5 seconds.
```

But the browser will put that temporary page in the history. My question is what HTTP status code may I use in this situation to tell the browser not record the URL?

Comment: Can you clarify "not record the URL"? Do you mean "the URL should not show up in browser history", or do you mean "the page should not be cached"?

Comment: @SripathiKrishnan I meant the URL should not show up in browser history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status code should be 200.  If you do not want browser to cache, you should set Cache related meta fields.